# Accesor method is not recieving var from mutator method

Tags: java, eclipse

I am making a basic calculator on eclipse, java. But I have a problem with one of the methods as it doesn't accept the right variable.

I know that the problem is in the `calculateDifference()` and `setCurrentValue()` method.

```
public class Dollar {

    static int startingValue = 2650;
    static int currentValue;
    static int dollars;
    static int differenceValue = calculateDifference();

    static void setDollarQuantity (int dollarValue) {
        dollars = dollarValue;
    }

    static void setCurrentValue(int currentDollar) {
        currentValue = currentDollar;
    }

    static int calculateDifference() {
        return ( currentValue - startingValue) * dollars;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        setCurrentValue(2780);
        setDollarQuantity(111);
        calculateDifference();
    }
}
```

The expected result from the `calculateDifference` method was 14,430 but the actual is 0. I have found the problem which was the `calculateDifference` method is not accepting the currentValue as 2780, but 0. Anyone can help me and modify my code?

Comment: You are not using the return value of `calculateDiffrence();`. Have you put your complete code here?

Comment: I think I have made a mistake while copying the code the real code should be like this 
System.out.println(diffrenceValue); instead of calculateDiffrence();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
static int diffrenceValue = calculateDifference();
```

to

```
static int differenceValue;
```

and in main()

```
calculateDifference();
```

to

```
differenceValue = calculateDifference();
System.out.println(differenceValue);
```

This way you will set the `differenceValue` after the other variables are initialized with correct value, not before.